# Windows Disk I/O 100% at boot for 20 Minutes

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot

I have a fast computer (quad-core i7, 3.5 Ghz, 24 GB of RAM, Windows 8.1) and I installed a new hard drive less than a year ago that was supposed to be as fast as you could buy for an HHD and not an SSD.

On boot, the computer is extremely slow for about 20 minutes (literally 20 minutes). Nothing will load. Opening programs will just hang.

Went into Resource Monitor and found that my disk I/O is at 100% that entire period. In fact, it looks like one program is just going to town on my disk: `CompatTelRunner.exe`. I've Googled it, but there are hardly any results, so I don't know what service this is.

Here are some screen shots at 5 and 10 minutes in:
[image]
[image]

It could be a hard drive issue ([Windows 8.1 Update 1 Disk Usage 100%](https://superuser.com/questions/759152/windows-8-1-update-1-disk-usage-100)), but HD Tune shows burst rate at 22.8 MB/s and average around 81.0 MB/s

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2952664

Comment: [What is the Application Block Detector on Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/758882)

Comment: Thanks for the links. Do you know what CompatTelRunner does?

Comment: No. If I did I would have answered the question :/ Something to do with MS collecting data for something to do with checking the compatibilty of something.

Comment: Windows 10 maybe?

Comment: Could well be...

Comment: As mentioned above, the title is "Compatibility update for upgrading Windows 7", and the release date of CompatTelRunner.exe is 29-Jun-2015. It would seem that Windows Update KB2952664 needs to be uninstalled from *Installed Updates*. This reinforces my apprehension at MS *forcing* updates on Windows 10 Home.

Comment: It's on Windows 8, though?

Comment: [Its part of this update for W8](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2976978)

Comment: Let it run till end and then don't reboot - hibernate Windows 8.1 so it will not restart its "evil" doings ;) Or just uninstall KB2976978 (and block/hide later on Windows Update).

Comment: @snayob - Good thing there is a tool to uninstall trouble updates then.

Comment: I have a clean install of Windows 10 Pro and I also have this issue of CompatTelRunner.  Mine doesn't run for 20 minutes but it does run on boot and uses almost all my hard drive resources making the PC useless until its done.  Doesn't always happen though, it seems related to next boot after patching or some arbitrary schedule.

Answer (score 184):

You can disable the scheduled tasks that starts CompatTelTunner.exe by looking in the Task Scheduler.
*Computer Management – System Tools – Task Schedule Library – Microsoft – Windows – Application Experience*
**or**
`Start - Run - taskschd.msc`
**Name:** Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser
**Location:** \Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience
Collects program telemetry information if opted-in to the Microsoft Customer Experience Improvement Program.
Right click on “Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser” and select “Disable”
By default, it is set to start if there is ANY network connection.

The executable is located here:
`C:\Windows\System32\CompatTelRunner.exe`

You may also want to look at the following:
Customer Experience Improvement Program states

> If the user has consented to participate in the Windows
>   Customer Experience Improvement Program, this job collects and sends
>   usage data to Microsoft. However, it is set to run even if opted out
>   Siuf (under Feedback)

Comment: omg i wish linux or mac played this game i want so i can get rid of this awful OS thanks

Comment: MS Seems to have found a workaround. It was running this morning despite being disabled.

Comment: didn't work for me, the task started anyway.

Comment: I can't believe it's a microsoft tool, I thought I had a  virus.

Answer (score 24):

Short answer: it's "legitimate" disk usage by a MS tool, just like the MsMpEng (MS Malware Protection Engine) it's scanning your disk regularly.

How do I get to that statement?
Well, I have had the same behaviour on my Win 7 machines and did some digging. First, I used the Resource Monitor and found CompatTelRunner.exe reading what looked like all of my disks/files, like e.g. a malware scanner does. During that time it was also writing to a directory ( C:\windows\temp\compattelemetrylogs ). When it was done with the disk work, it started showing network activity *on the upstream* (matching what is mentioned in an [Avast Forum Entry](https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=174018.0)). I checked the above directory and found confirmed what the file and directory names hint at: it seems to be "Compatibility Telemetry Information". That means that MS seems to be scanning all PCs that have the update installed (i.e. all that are Win10-compatible), collecting information about all installed programs and features (read: about "everything"), and then sends at least part of that information or a status report to MS servers (I have not network-screened it... yet).

The frequent re-releases of the update can mean many different things, like compatibility updates, scan rule updates, anything, really. However, I don't like that MS scrapes all of my machines (and everyone else's, too) for information and *does not tell me about it*. Even if that information may be helpful or even necessary in providing the seamless upgrade path to Win10.

If you don't want to go to Win10 on that machine, you should consider removing the upgrade.

Comment: This is very bad and is still true today 2017. Someone need to do a deep analysis on what exactly is being uploaded.

Comment: With all due respect, but in my not so humble opinion, 100% disk usage is **never** legitimate for what *should* be a background tool. It's terrible as the entire PC becomes nearly unusable. I don't get what is so difficult about budgetting and prioritizing resources. Hint, MS: The *foreground* process that the user is actually working with should *always* be prioritized over a background job. I really don't get that after all these years and all these billions of profit Windows still gets this wrong.

Comment: @StijndeWitt I totally agree... I usually do not really mind having the OS vendor take a look at how I use their product provided they bring updates and guarantee a minimum security so I can peacefully use my hardware and do the stuff I need or want to. But this is exactly the point here... with such "fore"ground process running at 100% hard disk usage, it's making my laptop totally unusable for several minutes... hic... it's my professional laptop, does my company want me to wait for 20min every morning, don't think so!

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue also (I'm on Windows 7, but the issue is identical). Many [sources](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2930713/microsoft-windows/microsoft-re-re-releases-kb-2952664-kb-2976978-and-kb-2977759.html) have found that KB2976978 has been re-released numerous times; it's likely that the version of the patch you have is an older release with glitchy behavior. Uninstall it from `appwiz.cpl` and reboot. Windows Update will re-offer it next time it checks for updates. I went ahead and reinstalled it and everything seems fine now.